# Modelstate errors not shown correctly

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I have a strange problem with the modelstate errors in my asp.net webapi2 (not core) being displayed only as:

> \"\"

This is my controllers code:

```
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {            
            Log.Verbose("Modelstate NOT valid");

            var errorList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject((from item in ModelState.Values
                             from error in item.Errors
                             select error.ErrorMessage).ToList());

            Log.Verbose("modelstate errors: " + errorList);
            Log.Verbose("resulting object:" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(computerObject));
            return BadRequest("Modelstate not valid" + errorList);

        }

        Log.Verbose("Modelstate is valid");
        return (Ok("dumped + jsonitem));
```

I think this worked at the beginning but now it is displaying lots of unuseful stuff:

```
{
    "Message": "Modelstate not valid[\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",
\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",
\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",
\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",
\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"
The ComputerOsClientComputer field is required.\"]" 
}
```

I interted line breaks for better readability. The original result looks like this:

```
{
    "Message": "Modelstate not valid[\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"The ComputerOs field is required.\"]"
}
```

While I can definately see that "The ComputerOs field is required" I don't know what all the other stuff is supposed to mean :/
Once I resolve the "ComputerOs field is required error the rest stays there. So it has to mean something.

Can anyone please enlighten me?

Thanks a lot!

Steffen

Comment: Well, you are not filtering for properties that don't have errors, so that prints `""`

Comment: why am I not doing it? Am I not only getting "from errors in item.errors"? I thought that these are only errors? Even when I correct "ComputerOsClientComputer" the modelstate is still shown as invalid. So there has to be another error otherwise it should be valid, shouldn't it?

Comment: I cannot answer you that, since you didn't post your model nor with what data you are calling the action

Answer (score 0):

found it!

One part of my json request was malformed.

I did not post my request here because it is pretty big and I didn't know which part caused the error.
While my model states this:

```
public class ComputerLocalGroups
{
    public string Groupname { get; set; }
    public int LocalGroupId { get; set; }
}
```

what I sent in my json request was

```
{
"ComputerLocalGroupsCurrent":[{"Access Control Assistance Operators", 11}]
}
```

instead of:

```
{
"ComputerLocalGroupsCurrent":[{"Groupname":"Access Control Assistance Operators", "LocalGroupId":11}]
}
```

It's very odd that it causes this kind of "error message" instead of something more helpful, but it was my fault in the beginning so I can't complain :D